# Server Error on Field Types

Tags: extension

I am trying to navigate to my Field Types area in the admin and I get this error:

The website encountered an error while retrieving http://development.pixelsandcode.co.uk/pixels/index.php?S=16d12918ee792c9a1d8491483dea63565199f9fc&D=cp&C=addons_fieldtypes. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

I've removed all the add-ons I added post installation, but I am still getting the same error.

I'm kind of new to EE, so any help would be great.

Comment: This is a generic browser error so doesn't really point us to anything unfortunately. Take a look at the FireBug Network tab to see if that shows any clues as to why the page isn't loading. Do you see anything? Is this message coming up immediately or after a certain amount of time? Sounds like something on that page is timing out to me.

Comment: Hmm, well this is in the network tab in Firebug.

http://cl.ly/NBYk

Comment: Tada... Looks like a 500 error on that page. Take a look at your PHP error logs to see if there is more information there. You should also contact your web host and have them see if they can find why the page is throwing a 500 error. You can also try removing everything from your .htaccess file and reload that page. I find my 500 errors are usually related to fat fingers in the .htaccess file code.

Comment: This is a local site on my machine.  Quick look on my php log and its the magpie rss feed that is causing it it seems.

Comment: I removed that plugin and still its not loading.

Comment: Ok I gave up.  Decided to do a clean installation.  It was a local site with no real data in it, so happy to do that.

Comment: And a clean install fixed the issue?